# MySQL DELAY_KEY_WRITE TAble Value

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know how to find the DELAY_KEY_WRITE value for a specific table?  It's a table option for the Create Table syntax. The table was created a while ago by someone else and i need to know if it has DELAY_KEY_WRITE enabled.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable
```

It will show `DELAY_KEY_WRITE = 1` if it's enabled, won't show anything if it's not.